# Devise gem to check encrypted password with current password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, bcrypt

In my Ruby on Rails application, we are using devise gem `Encryptor` module to encrypt the password from login page. My user model has encrypted password and does not store password in raw form.

I have password update feature for user and need to check current password. I need to validate with the encrypted password from user model using devise encryptor module which uses bcrypt and klass . How can I achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise provides `valid_password?(raw_password_to_check)` method in your model for password checking

Comment: In my model I am having only encrypted password.what to do in valid password method.

Comment: It's already there, comes in `database_authenticatable` devise strategy, see https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable

Comment: I am not storing the raw password

Comment: Thanks got the answer